# Is it ok to use std::ignore in order to discard a return value of a function to avoid any related compiler warnings?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++14

I know that you can use `static_cast<void>`, but it just seems too verbose for me, and not reflecting the original intent that I want to discard a return value, not to cast it to anything.

Recently I stumbled upon [`std::ignore`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/ignore), which can accept a value of any type, the name is clear and readable, and to me it seems fitting.

I know that the initial intent was to use `std::ignore` alongside with [`std::tie`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) to discard any unwanted values, but I guess the original intent of `static_cast` was to actually cast values for some better reasons than discarding values so the compiler won't complain.

So, is it OK to use `std::ignore` for the purpose I described in the question?

For example:

```
std::ignore = std::transform(...);
```

Comment: As far as I know `std::ignore` is only defined in terms of its use in `std::tie`. Strictly speaking, I think it would have to be `std::tie(std::ignore) = std::tie(std::transform(...));`.

Comment: Your usage looks valid.  @FrançoisAndrieux see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/ignore) - the first example is not related to `std::tie`  (`std::ignore = dontIgnoreMe();`).

Comment: @wohlstad See the top of the page you linked : *"While the behavior of std::ignore outside of std::tie is not formally specified, some code guides recommend using std::ignore to avoid warnings from unused return values of [[nodiscard]] functions."* cppreference agrees isn't specified. It'll probably work for any given compiler, but it seems to technically be unspecified.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I was just about to edit my comment. I agree it is not clearly specified. But the example does use it in that way. I thought the cppreference examples are based on firm specifications. The first example is described as _"Demonstrates the use of std::ignore together with a [[nodiscard]] function."_.

Comment: @wohlstad It is a wiki after all. It's usually pretty accurate but there are no guaranties.  Checking the latest standard, you can search for `ignore` [here](https://eel.is/c++draft/libraryindex) and (besides the stream function) it only appears as part of tuple creation.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux got it. I usually treat cppreference.com as a good substitution for the actual reference, but I guess it has its limits ...

Comment: Regarding using `static_cast<void>`, this is one case where it is generally harmless to use an explicit conversion to `void` like `(void)my_function();`. Nobody can use the result, by definition, which eliminates most of the risks related to using them. And it is a relatively well known convention, so shouldn't act as a red flag or cause for confusion or concern.

Comment: BTW, `std::transform` doesn't return a `[[nodiscard]]`. so `std::ignore =` can even be removed :-), no warnings expected (else we would prefix any expression by it as `std::ignore = std::cout << "hello"` :) ).

Comment: @Jarod42 not only compiler warnings are there, but also warnings from other static code analysis tools :((

Comment: `// my_lint_tool_ignore_flag` might be an alternative too. (or maybe the warning is more subtle that just ignoring the return value).

Comment: Please consider expanding the shown line of (pseudo) code into a [mre], with the exact warnings from the compiler and code analysis tools (which ones?) you used.

Comment: while you can do it, why would you? `std::transform` isn't a no-discard, in fact it alters something passed to it. And, unless some mistakes were made, `[[nodiscard]]` functions are pure, i.e. they have no side effect and do not alter their arguments, so they are literally a no-op o.o

Comment: Just use `(void)`. Everyone understands what that's doing and it's very idiomatic at this point.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, it is okay. In fact, it is considered much better style by some people.

> Never cast to `(void)` to ignore a `[[nodiscard]]` return value. If you deliberately want to discard such a result, first think hard about whether that is really a good idea (there is usually a good reason the author of the function or of the return type used `[[nodiscard]]` in the first place). If you still think it’s appropriate and your code reviewer agrees, use `std::ignore =` to turn off the warning which is simple, portable, and easy to grep.

- [CppCoreGuidelines ES.48: Avoid casts](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#es48-avoid-casts)

*Note: [Herb Sutter committed the guideline](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/pull/1685). With the `std::ignore` rule, you can consistently teach not to use casts, and don't have to make an exception for casting to `void`.*

An argument against `std::ignore` is that it is only defined in terms of its effect in `std::tie`:

> ```cpp
> template<class... TTypes>
> constexpr tuple<TTypes&...> tie(TTypes&... t) noexcept;
> ```
>
> *Returns*: `tuple<TTypes&...>(t...)`. When an argument in `t` is `ignore`, assigning any value to the corresponding tuple element has no effect.

- [[utilities] `std::tie`](https://eel.is/c++draft/utilities#lib:tie)

This is mostly a philosophical issue though. In every major standard library, `std::ignore` is implemented in such a way that you can do `std::ignore = ...` on its own, and this may soon be well-defined. See [P2968: Make `std::ignore` a first-class object](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2023/p2968r0.html).

In the end, it's stylistic preference. You can use `(void)`, `static_cast<void>`, or `std::ignore`. They are all acceptable, and which one to use is a matter of opinion.
What matters is that you use a consistent style throughout your project, i.e. if you use `std::ignore` to discard results in one place, use it everywhere.

Answer (score 5):

In theory, `std::ignore`'s `operator=` could be implemented as:

```
[[nodiscard]] auto& operator=(auto&&...) const { return *this; }
```

So instead of suppressing compiler warnings, assigning to `std::ignore` could *cause* a warning.

And `std::tuple`'s `operator=` could do something like this, to suppress the warning when `std::ignore` is part of a `tuple`:

```
(static_cast<void>(std::get<I>(*this) = std::get<I>(rhs)), ...);
```

In practice, no implementation defines `std::ignore` like this.

Whether it is OK to use `std::ignore =` depends on whether you want to rely on the fact that no implementation uses `[[nodiscard]]` in the definition of `std::ignore`. I, personally, would rather not rely on this undocumented fact.

Comment: You might as well consider a hypothetical implementation that `= delete`s the `operator =` for `std::ignore`, and wraps the assignment in `std::tuple` in an `if constexpr (!std::is_same_v<decltype(std::ignore), […]>)`.